# Tangerine app security warning?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, security

I recently got the *Essential phone* and I started downloading all my apps back. I downloaded the Tangerine banking app, and I got this security warning as soon as I opened the app.

"It seems your device has had unauthorized modifications to its operating system. Using this device for your banking could compromise the security of your personal information"

[image]

Has anyone else got this with the app or is this a problem? I bought the phone brand new straight from the Telus store. I haven't done any modding or anything to it so not sure why the app is giving me this warning.

Comment: Is the USB debugging enabled? That could be a reason.

Comment: @beeshyams Checked, no it's not enabled.

Comment: - Where did you downloaded the app from?. - Is there any pending os update?. - can you retry using USB debugging mode enabled?. Just revert after that. - is your phone rooted or is having su binary on it?. - did you bought it new officially from their website?. - is your phones status official (bootloader, recovery, etc)?.

Comment: I downloaded it from the regular Goolge Play Store. No I phone is up to date with the latest that it says. My phone isn't rooted or anything else changed, I literally just bought it out right straight from the Telus store and started downloading my apps, and then saw that warning.

Comment: It's time to return the phone. You're not supposed to be worried in the first place